# Summing a list in Python - within a tuple and another list

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

Not sure if it's a dup - will delete if so, just haven't found one for this specific scenario. I have a complex list full of tuples, which contain strings and lists.

I need to replace the deepest lists with int values, which are the sum of those lists. I've tried half a dozen loop combinations to tackle it - nothing seems to work.

```
[('MED', [1, 1]), ('COP', [3, 1]), ('GRO', [1, 5]), ('RRE', [5, 3]), ('PRO', [4, 6])]
```

Needs to become:

```
[('MED', 2), ('COP', 4), ('GRO', 6), ('RRE', 8), ('PRO', 10)]
```

So that I can return the new list combo sorted by the values of the summed lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a concise, readable comprehension with something like:

```
[(abbr, sum(t)) for abbr, t in l]
```

result:

```
[('MED', 2), ('COP', 4), ('GRO', 6), ('RRE', 8), ('PRO', 10)]
```

Comment: This is better than the other two which are implementing using indexes. It looks a lot cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`

**Ex:**

```
lst = [('MED', [1, 1]), ('COP', [3, 1]), ('GRO', [1, 5]), ('RRE', [5, 3]), ('PRO', [4, 6])]
print(list(map(lambda x: (x[0], sum(x[1])), lst)))
```

---

or `list comprehension`

**Ex:**

```
print([(i[0], sum(i[1])) for i in lst])
```

**Output:**

```
[('MED', 2), ('COP', 4), ('GRO', 6), ('RRE', 8), ('PRO', 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
oldlst = [('MED', [1, 1]), ('COP', [3, 1]), ('GRO', [1, 5]), ('RRE', [5, 3]), ('PRO', [4, 6])]

newlst = list([(i[0], sum(i[1])) for i in oldlst])
```

Check [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HyWKjdgfN).

Answer (score 1):

Let's use list comprehensions to solve it -

```
myList = [('MED', [1, 1]), ('COP', [3, 1]), ('GRO', [1, 5]), ('RRE', [5, 3]), ('PRO', [4, 6])]
myList_out = [(i[0],sum(i[1])) for i in myList]
myList_out
    [('MED', 2), ('COP', 4), ('GRO', 6), ('RRE', 8), ('PRO', 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [collections.defaultdict.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
xList = [('MED', [1, 1]), ('COP', [3, 1]), ('GRO', [1, 5]), ('RRE', [5, 3]), ('PRO', [4, 6])]
testDict = defaultdict(int)
for key, val in xList:           
        testDict[key] = val[0] + val[1]

print(testDict.items())
```

OUTPUT:
[image: out]

Comment: ok why would anyone do this when there are simpler and more verbose ways of doing it? This seems like a lot of bloat for a simple task. Did you seriously have to import a module for this?

Comment: What can I say, I don't like going the easy way! :p

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [('MED', [1, 1]),('COP', [3, 1]),('GRO', [1, 5]),('RRE', [5, 3]),('PRO', [4, 6])]

print [(text, sum(num)) for text, num in lst]
```

result:

```
[('MED', 2), ('COP', 4), ('GRO', 6), ('RRE', 8), ('PRO', 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
l1 = [('MED', [1, 1]), ('COP', [3, 1]), ('GRO', [1, 5]), ('RRE', [5, 3]), ('PRO', [4, 6])]

mod_l1 = [(abbr, sum(t)) for abbr, t in l1]

required_l1 = sorted(mod_l1, key=lambda order: order[1])
```

result:

```
[('MED', 2), ('COP', 4), ('GRO', 6), ('RRE', 8), ('PRO', 10)]
```